# Cron cluster with one Redis instance and multiple server roles

Tags: node.js, redis, cron

I am trying to create a clustered Cronjob using
`cron-cluster` and `redis`
on Node.js. We are running multiple servers with different roles (production, staging, test) and the same codebase. They are all connected to the same Redis instance.

How do I make `cron-cluster` run only once on each role?
Currently, it picks only one server across the whole fleet (production, staging, test) and runs everything there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue with [cron-cluster](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron-cluster) library. 
To solve it, you should pass a unique key, while initializing an instance. For example:

```
const ClusterCronJob = require('cron-cluster')(redisClient, { key: leaderKey }).CronJob;
```

Where `{ key: leaderKey }` can be taken as follow:

```
const leaderKey = process.env.NODE_ENV;
```